# I have made a AR card game in unity but every time i press one of my buttons i get a null reference error and the button doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Here is the code could anyone tell me where i am going wrong please?
I need the buttons to access my methods which will compare the two cards on one stat, giving the winning player a point but when i press these buttons i get the error 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public int player1Score = 5;
    public int player2Score = 5;
    public bool gameEnded = false;
    public bool GameOver = false;
    public Card[] player1Hand;
    public Card[] player2Hand;
    //public GameObject GameOverPannel;
    public Text uitext;

    public class Card
    {
        public string cardName;
        public int year;
        public int fame;
        public int breathtaking;
        public int everyday;
        public int rating;
        public int allCards;
        
        public Card(string cardName, int year, int fame, int breathtaking, int everyday, int rating)
        {
            this.cardName = cardName;
            this.year = year;
            this.fame = fame;
            this.breathtaking = breathtaking;
            this.everyday = everyday;
            this.rating = rating;
        }


    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        Card AstonMartinDBSCard = new Card("AstonMartinDBS",1964, 99, 48, 11, 84);
        Card BatmoblieCard = new Card("Batmoblie",1989, 100, 48, 3, 100);
        Card BumblebeeCard = new Card("Bumblebee",2007, 87, 34, 29, 63);
        Card DelorianCard = new Card("Delorian",1985, 98, 45, 14, 90);
        Card GeneralLeeCard = new Card("GeneralLee",1979, 79, 28, 20, 71);
        Card ECTO1Card = new Card("ECTO1",1984, 96, 46, 8, 68);
        Card HerbieCard = new Card("Herbie",1968, 83, 22, 30, 64);
        Card KITTCard = new Card("KITT",1982, 84, 28, 18, 83);
        Card FootmobileCard = new Card("Footmobile",1960, 93, 41, 2, 43);
        Card MysteryMachineCard = new Card("MysteryMachine",1969, 95, 31, 6, 52);

        Card[] allCards = new Card[] { AstonMartinDBSCard, BatmoblieCard, BumblebeeCard, DelorianCard, GeneralLeeCard, ECTO1Card, HerbieCard, KITTCard, FootmobileCard, MysteryMachineCard };

        // Shuffle the cards randomly
        System.Random rng = new System.Random();
        int n = allCards.Length;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            Card temp = allCards[k];
            allCards[k] = allCards[n];
            allCards[n] = temp;
        }

        player1Hand = new Card[5]{
            allCards[0], allCards[1], allCards[2], allCards[3], allCards[4]
        };
        player2Hand = new Card[5]{
            allCards[5], allCards[6], allCards[7], allCards[8], allCards[9]
        };
        
       /* foreach (Card card in player1Hand) {
        uitext.text += "player 1's cards are " + card.cardName + "\n";
        }*/
        foreach (Card card in player1Hand) {
        Debug.Log("player 1s cards are  " + card.cardName);
        }
        foreach (Card card in player2Hand) {
        Debug.Log("player 2s cards are  " + card.cardName);
        }
        Debug.Log("player1Hand[1]: " + player1Hand[1]);
        Debug.Log("player2Hand[1]: " + player2Hand[1]);

    }

    
    public void Year()
    {
        
        if (player1Hand[1].year > player2Hand[1].year)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 1 wins the round!");
                player1Score++;
                player2Score--;
            }
            else if (player2Hand[1].year > player1Hand[1].year)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 2 wins the round!");
                player2Score++;
                player1Score--;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("It's a tie!");
            }
            CheckWinner();
        
    }

    public void Fame()
    {
       
        if (player1Hand[2].fame > player2Hand[2].fame)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 1 wins the round!");
                player1Score++;
                player2Score--;
            }
            else if (player2Hand[2].fame > player1Hand[2].fame)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 2 wins the round!");
                player2Score++;
                player1Score--;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("It's a tie!");
            }
            CheckWinner();
           
    }

    public void Breathtaking()
    {
        
        if (player1Hand[3].breathtaking > player2Hand[3].breathtaking)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 1 wins the round!");
                player1Score++;
                player2Score--;
            }
            else if (player2Hand[3].breathtaking > player1Hand[3].breathtaking)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 2 wins the round!");
                player2Score++;
                player1Score--;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("It's a tie!");
            }
            CheckWinner();
           
    }

    public void Everyday()
    {   
       
        if (player1Hand[4].everyday > player2Hand[4].everyday)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 1 wins the round!");
                player1Score++;
                player2Score--;
            }
            else if (player2Hand[4].everyday > player1Hand[4].everyday)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 2 wins the round!");
                player2Score++;
                player1Score--;

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("It's a tie!");
            }
            CheckWinner();    
              
    }

    public void Rating()
    {
        
        if (player1Hand[5].rating > player2Hand[5].rating)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 1 wins the round!");
                player1Score++;
                player2Score--;
            }
            else if (player2Hand[5].rating > player1Hand[5].rating)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player 2 wins the round!");
                player2Score++;
                player1Score--;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("It's a tie!");
            }
            CheckWinner();
           
    }


    // to work out winners first to get 10 cards, do it by starting on, 5 +1 for win -1 for loss 
    
    public void CheckWinner()
{
    if (player1Score == 10)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player 1 wins the game!");
        gameEnded = true;
    }
    else if (player2Score == 10)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player 2 wins the game!");
        gameEnded = true;
    }
    if (gameEnded == true)
    {
       //GameOver = true; 
       SceneManager.LoadScene("EndGameScreen");
        
    }
}
    
}
```

I have tried testing different tings but nothing has worked

Comment: What method is your button calling when you click it?  And what line are you actually getting the error on?  This would be a great post on here to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: In Debug mode the compiler tells you exactly on which line number the error occurs.